# Custom "No messages in queue over x minutes" Azure alert rule does not pass validation

Tags: azure, queue, alert, rules

I want to create an **alert rule** in **Azure** to monitor when **a queue did not have any message over a time period** (one hour, for instance). Since I did not find any way to do this from the portal UI, I tried uploading an **ARM template** for the rule. The template is listed below:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "serviceBusNamespace": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the Service Bus Namespace."
        }
    },
    "serviceBusQueueName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the Service Bus Queue."
        }
    },
    "emailAddresses": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The email addresses to receive alerts."
        }
    },
    "messageThreshold": {
        "type": "int",
        "defaultValue": 0,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The number of active messages that triggers an alert."
        }
    },
    "noMessagesWindowSize": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "PT30M",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The time window for no messages alert."
        }
    },
    "noMessagesFrequency": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "PT5M",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The frequency to check for no messages."
        }
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts",
        "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
        "name": "[concat('no-messages-', parameters('serviceBusQueueName'))]",
        "location": "['germanywestcentral']",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Alert when no messages are received.",
            "severity": 3,
            "enabled": true,
            "condition": {
                "metricName": "IncomingMessages",
                "metricNamespace": "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'))]",
                "operator": "LessThan",
                "threshold": "[parameters('messageThreshold')]",
                "windowSize": "[parameters('noMessagesWindowSize')]",
                "timeAggregation": "Count",
                "dimensions": [
                    {
                        "name": "EntityName",
                        "value": "[parameters('serviceBusQueueName')]"
                    }
                ],
                "evaluationFrequency": "[parameters('noMessagesFrequency')]",
                "aggregationType": "Maximum",
                "treatMissingData": "UseZero"
            },
            "actions": [
                {
                    "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups', 'no-messages-action-group')]",
                    "webhookProperties": {}
                }
            ],
            "scopes": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'), '/queues/', parameters('serviceBusQueueName'))]"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
        "name": "no-messages-action-group",
        "location": "['germanywestcentral']",
        "properties": {
            "groupShortName": "no-messages",
            "enabled": true,
            "emailReceivers": [
                {
                    "name": "email",
                    "emailAddress": "[array(parameters('emailAddresses'))]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {}
}
```

This passes the JSON validation, but the final **Review + Create** validation gives the following error:

> {"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","target":"/[my-route]/Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts/no-messages-[sb-queue-name]","message":"Required property 'evaluationFrequency' not found in JSON. Path ''."}],"message":"The template deployment 'Microsoft.Template-20230427173620' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '[tracking-id]'. See inner errors for details."}

However, no other relevant info is provided by Microsoft. I tried removing the parameter for this property at all and feeding the property a hardcoded value, made sure it is smaller or equal to the lookback period, still the same error. I also tried renaming the parameter receiving a value for this property, the error did not go away. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!